# Ifstream with a char array

Tags: c++, stl, ifstream

How can I do this?
I am using Visual Studio 2010 C++.

```
char * Buffer = new char[Filesize];
//Fill it with data here

std::ifstream BinaryParse(Buffer, std::ios::binary);
if(BinaryParse.is_open())
{
   BinaryParse.read((char*)&Count, sizeof(unsigned int));
}
```

That does not work.
How can I make an ifstream behave in the same way as if it is reading a file, except reading from a char array?

Answer (score 1):

You can try istringstream, which uses a C++ string as the input stream.

Here is an example from [C++ reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istringstream/istringstream/):

```
// using istringstream constructors.
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  int n,val;
  string stringvalues;

  stringvalues = "125 320 512 750 333";
  istringstream iss (stringvalues,istringstream::in);

  for (n=0; n<5; n++) {
    iss >> val;
    cout << val*2 << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

You can find another example here: http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/strings/stringstream-example.html.

Comment: The std::string has a constructor with a char* argument, which you can use to convert your buffer to a std::string. See [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/).

Comment: I meant that when I do iss >> val (what if val == std::string)

Comment: val can be std::string: you can use iss >> str just like cin >> str.